# Is result of sys.exc_info() "stable" when its origin thread finishes?

Tags: python

Supposing I catch an exception inside a thread and store exc_info tuple somewhere. Then thread finishes. Is my exc_info content still accessible and correct, so I can interpret it later in other thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tuple you receive from `sys.exc_info()` can safely be passed to and used from other threads, even after the death of the thread the tuple came from. The references from the tuple keep things like stack state alive even when the thread is dead.

(You won't be able to access the tuple as `sys.exc_info()` from other threads, so you'll need to store it somewhere before the thread dies, but it sounds like you're aware of that.)